# ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE Persisted permission

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

If a user selects the root of the sd card for `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` permission and the app persists it, how does access work afterwards?  Would that simply act as the former `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, allowing simple `File` access in a manner prior to 4.4?

If not, how would one, for example, delete a file within a persisted root (please tell me it doesn't involve a popup every time)?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [oficial documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#file-directory-restrictions), starting from Android 11 an sd card root is not available to access with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

So you can't delete a file within a persisted root on Android 11.